# Android SQlite insert syntax errors

Tags: android, sqlite

There is a similar question on here but my situation is different.

```
07-13 13:03:11.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6268): Error inserting 2=Fri Jul 13 13:03:10   EDT 2012 WebView is exiting 1=Fri Jul 13 13:02:53 EDT 2012 Registering Device for Notifications 0=Fri Jul 13 13:02:41 EDT 2012 Device passed GCM requirements test

07-13 13:03:11.460: E/SQLiteDatabase(6268): android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "2": syntax error: , while compiling: INSERT INTO log(2,1,0) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

I'm trying to insert simple String values passed into ContentValues.

```
LogOpenHelper helper = new LogOpenHelper(this);
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
for (int i = 0; i < logReporter.getSize(); i++) {
        values.put(i + "", temp[i]);
    }
helper.getWritableDatabase().insert(TABLE_NAME, null, values);
    helper.close();

    cursor.close();
```

The above for loop simply takes all of my log messages out of a string[]. The string[] is filled throughout the application because I do not need constant Database access. Just Inserts and Queries at startup and shutdown for debugging

The strings i'm trying to insert a instances of Date + a String. Is there a certain character sequence that isn't allowed in the sqlite parser that I'm missing? I have to use ContentValues because an object of that type is a parameter to call insert().

Any ideas as to why the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For proper inserting you have to pass name of column as first argument in method `values.put()`.

Answer (score 0):

As is written you are inserting rows, with dynamical number of columns, count of which depends on **logReporter.getSize()**... That is likely not what you want.

Assuming you created your table with:

```
CREATE TABLE logtable (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, log_message_column TEXT);
```

You should try something like this:

```
SQLiteDatabase database = helper.getWritableDatabase();

for (String logMessage: logReporter) {
    values.put("log_message_column", logMessage);
    database.insert("logtable", null, values);
}

helper.close()
```

Then you will have your logs messages in the column **logMessage** of the table **logtable**.

But why you do use database for your logs? Why do not use simple *Log.d()* or write logs to some file on SD-Card?

Comment: It's an idea that was tossed around for remote debugging. So that users can have a log file to email to the developers in the event of a crash. It's my first app so that pretty much sums it up

Comment: I think, you are also interested in getting StackTrace on appcrash... this also can be made easy by calling [**Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()**](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler%28java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler%29) on your main thread and implementing your own exceptionHandler... but this is subject for another question which was already asked somewhere here on StackOverflow